# Default Values for Child-Class Attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say in my schema I have a users table with an attribute field of pets that's default to ["dogs"]:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.text    "pets",     default: ["dogs"],    array: true
    ...
```

I have a model `FriendlyUser` that inherits from class `User`: `class FriendlyUser < User`

Thus, when a `FriendlyUser` is created, the type is "FriendlyUser". But I would like `FriendlyUser` to have pets set to a default of dogs AND cats: ["dogs", "cats"]

Is this possible with a migration, or must this be done in the class (by overriding an `initialize` method, using `after_initialize`, `before_create`, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Default values in Rails migrations aren't intended to handle logic like this. From the database side, it might be *technically* possible using a trigger to populate the data on insert based on the value in the type column, but that's probably more trouble and complication than it's worth.

Setting the value in a `before_validation` callback is probably your best bet. And since you're using inheritance you can override the callback in the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Since STI is using one table for multiple models, default values in the database layer will make it harder for your models to have different characteristics. Thus, I think you should stick with moving the default value logic to your application logic where you can define model specific behaviour.